# Samples from the double Schechter luminosity funcion

Tags: galaxy, luminosity, resource-request

I want to produce samples from a double Schechter luminosity function.

Ideally, I am looking for a python implementation of this problem but am open to other tools if necessary.

Do you know of any such package that will facilitate this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to draw a random luminosity from a PDF given by a double Schechter? The rather old package [CosmoloPy](https://github.com/roban/CosmoloPy) can return the cumulative distribution of a [regular Schechter and other LFs](https://roban.github.io/CosmoloPy/docAPI/cosmolopy.luminosityfunction-pysrc.html), so perhaps you can modify and put in the extra term?

Comment: That is what I meant, yes. Thank you for the link - looks promising!